# How do I use VMWare Player inside an Azure Windows 7 VM?

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I'm geting this message from VMWare: "VMware Player and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running VMware Player."

I'm running a Windows 7 VM on Azure, and I can't find anything to do with Hyper-V other than 5 services which I have disabled and stopped but I still get the same message. I can't find anything to do with "roles", there's nothing in Accessories or Computer->Manage.

Comment: Roles are only used on Windows Server operating systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense, Azure **is** Hyper-V. The problem isn't Hyper-V on your Windows 7 VM. It's that *you can't nest one VM inside another*.

You will not be able to use VMWare Player as a *guest* in Azure or any other cloud service. You may be able to use a VMWare guest directly in the cloud host, or convert it for use in your cloud host, but you will not be able to run it inside an existing VM.